# How to connect Firefox to Chrome to transfer h264 via WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, webrtc, sdp

I try to connect Firefox 45 to Chrome 51dev to transfer h264 video. Firefox to Firefox and Chrome to Chrome works perfectly. But Firefox to Chrome transfers vp8 video even though I set the priority h264.

To set the codec priority I used this link: https://miguelpdl.github.io/WebRTC-codelab/session06/lab/html/step03.html

On the answer side remote description contains:

```
m=video 53100 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 107 100 101 116 117 96 97 99 98
...
a=rtpmap:107 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:101 VP9/90000
a=rtpmap:116 red/90000
a=rtpmap:117 ulpfec/90000
a=rtpmap:96 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=rtpmap:98 rtx/90000
```

But local description contains only:

```
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 100
...
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
```

Can I connect Firefox to Chrome to transfer h264?

Comment: How are you verifying that Chrome to Chrome sends H.264?

Comment: By chrome://webrtc-internals. You can see [here](https://i.gyazo.com/6895f17080c9542eecbd7899bc175c6c.png)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome does not yet support H.264. For proof, see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u6ztkf1r/) which removes the VP8 codec.

The fiddle lets you cut'n'paste offer/answers to make a connection between two tabs or browsers, but for now, just paste the offer into a text editor and look at it:

You'll find that Firefox offers H.264 to spec:

```
a=rtpmap:126 H264/90000
a=rtpmap:97 H264/90000
```

whereas Chrome offers VP8 only, in spite of us just having removed it:

```
a=rtpmap:100 VP8/90000
```

So when you say it works from Chrome to Chrome, I think you're really seeing VP8.

They are [apparently working H.264](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/6417796455989248) though.

**Update:** Apparently H.264 support is [behind a flag in Chrome 50](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/8ov4YW6HLgo). Enable it with:

```
chrome://flags/#enable-webrtc-h264-with-openh264-ffmpeg
```

Comment: I use Chrome 51.0.2700.0 dev-m and _enable-webrtc-h264-with-openh264-ffmpeg_ flag is enabled.

Comment: @RomaRomin that looks like a bug. Unsure which browser to file it on.